# Using PARTITION BY and the order is messing up when I insert. Why?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I wanted to order the employees by time they started an assignment, so that the results would look like this:

[image]

So I am using a query similar to:

```
SELECT a.employeename, b.assignmenttime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.employeename order by b.assignmenttime) sequence
FROM  emplyee a, tasks b  
WHERE a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.employeename, b.assignmenttime
```

This is inside a procedure and every time the procedure gets called I want the results to be written to a table. 
So I have:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Emp,Time,Sequence)
SELECT a.employeename, b.assignmenttime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.employeename order by b.assignmenttime) sequence
FROM  emplyee a, tasks b  
WHERE a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.employeename, b.assignmenttime;
commit;
```

This is all fine except when the records are written to the table the order gets messed up sometimes and I end up with

[image]

As you can see the sequence is not in order. A normal query always returns the records in the right order but why when I call the procedure the records get written out of order in the table? What do I have to do to fix this? Using oracle 10g

Comment: "*the order gets messed up*" - the order of a table can't be "messed up" because rows in a table ***NOT*** "ordered". Unless you specify an `order by` when *selecting*, the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes. Using `order by` is the only way to ensure a sort order in a select statement.

Comment: Ok , you have answered by question. I understand that without an 'order by' clause there is no guaranteed order when selecting from table. Thanks!

Comment: What one can do is list columns (in the SELECT clause) in the order in which you want them to be ordered, but in Oracle SQL there's only an order as specified in the ORDER BY clause, and it does not default to the SELECT clause if the ORDER BY is missing.